# Firefox quick search extension idea. Is it possible?[see details]

Tags: firefox, search

I use search sites very often.
And in *99%* of cases search results that i need contained in first 3 links,that search engine returns.
Is it possible from programming point to write extension for Firefox,that satisfies next use case:
**1.** user clicks icon
**2.** modal window appeared
**3.** select search engine(e.g. *Google,Yahoo or Yandex*...any other)
**4.** write search criterion
**5.** click OK
**6.** 3 new tabs opened in browser with corresponding sites

It seems, that most complex part is to open 3 fist sites in new tabs - someth. like with using Selenium and XPATH.

Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in fact, this is possible with just a Greasemonkey script. If you're using just a greasemonkey script,  I'd advise making it run on google.com, then you can add a listener to the submit button, then GM_openInTab all the necessary pages.